# How to install elementary OS AppCenter on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

elementary OS 0.4 *"Loki"* debuted an interesting new feature: [AppCenter](https://elementary.io/#appcenter), a 'pay what you want' app store. It features many well designed Indie apps.

[image: elementary OS AppCenter]

I'd like to try this new AppCenter and the apps it offers. Is there an easy way to get the AppCenter on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS you can install AppCenter from [elementary OS PPA](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

### Step 1: Add the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt update
```

### Step 1.1: For releases newer than 16.04LTS

If you're on an [Ubuntu release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) newer than 16.04 LTS, use the following [Daily PPA](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily) instead:

*(I have had success with daily on 16.04 as well)*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt update
```

### Step 2: Add elementary Apps repo

AppCenter is supposed to add this repository automatically, but that may not always happen. Add the repo and it's key:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter $(lsb_release -sc) main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list'
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/appcenter.asc http://packages.elementary.io/key.asc
sudo apt update
```

### Step 3: Install AppCenter

Then all you have to do is install the `appcenter` package:

```
sudo apt install appcenter
```

If the installation fails due to unmet dependencies on 16.04 LTS, add this [PPA for PackageKit](https://launchpad.net/~ximion/+archive/ubuntu/packagekit)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ximion/packagekit
sudo apt update
```

and try again to install. When it's installed successfully, the launcher for AppCenter should show up in App Dash.

[image: App Center in Dash]

Or you can just launch it from the terminal as:

```
appcenter
```

Or:

```
io.elementary.appcenter
```

Comment: Thanx 4 the answer! However, I thought the [elementary OS PPA](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=xenial) isn't supposed to be added to vanilla Ubuntu. It holds a lot of packages, some of which can possibly break Ubuntu. Besides, the PPA packages target Ubuntu 16.04LTS (elementary OS being LTS based). So, not sure if it'll work easily on intermediate Ubuntu releases. Anyway, I'll definitely test your method and let you know the results. 

Comment: I tested on the latest 17.10 daily and it it worked! I just had an extra step of manually changing the PPA release from _artful_ to _xenial_ (coz elementary OS packages target Ubuntu 16.04LTS Xenial base). Surprisingly the PPA didn't break any Ubuntu packages.

However, the appcenter wouldn't install on Ubuntu 16.04LTS due to missing dependencies. That seems to be strange considering elementary OS is 16.04LTS based. Anyway, I think I'll figure it out, eventually...

Comment: @HEXcube Yeah, that is strange.  I have it installed on two different 16.04 hosts here and they both seem to be working fine.  I do, however, really like the Appcenter.  Pretty nice and neatly laid out.  :)

Comment: _"there are other non-EoL Ubuntu releases, like Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"_ @EliahKagan  Oops! I didn't think about 14.04LTS. But since AppCenter is available only for 16.04LTS and up, I think it's better to mark that in the answer.

Comment: _"you'll have to change the apt sources to point to xenial is pretty vague"_ @EliahKagan I'll link to another answer showing how to do that.

Comment: _"I have it installed on two different 16.04 hosts"_ @Terrance  Did u encounter the missing dependencies? Have u added any other PPAs or repos which contain the dependencies? 

Comment: @EliahKagan I see u took care of the vague "change apt sources" instruction 

Comment: @EliahKagan  I'm thinking of adding a spoiler section for non-16.04 LTS users. Inside it would be an one-liner command to change the release name. What do u think?

Comment: @HEXcube That sounds reasonable to me. I don't know for sure exactly what you'll say, but further editing is always possible, so I say go for it! I think it may be useful also to explain how to check if this is actually necessary, since presumably 16.04 won't be the last release the PPA provides `appcenter` for, and users may read this answer years from now.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yeah, this answer'd probably need an edit once Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is out. For now, I'm just going with "16.04 LTS and newer"

Comment: Tried again on vanilla Ubuntu 16.04LTS liveboot and failed! Got dependency problems on these packages: _elementary-keyring_, _packagekit_, _libappstream4_, _libpackagekit-glib2-18_ and _appstream-data-pantheon-loki-stable_. I had universe and multiverse enabled too. @Terrance U sure u tested on 16.04LTS with no other elementary PPAs added? Can u reproduce on Ubuntu 16.04LTS liveboot or VM?

Comment: @HEXcube 16.04LTS is all I run right now.  I don't run any of the non-LTS as I don't like to reinstall my OS every 6 months.  However, I did make changes to my answer here that should help.  Try using the `Daily` PPA instead of the `Stable` and add the `Appcenter` PPA I show so that the pay what you want apps show up.

Comment: @Terrance I'll try the daily PPA. And about the apps repo, it'll get automatically added by AppCenter once it's up and running. However, adding the repo'd speed up the process by one step, I guess.

Comment: @Terrance Adding the daily PPA on 16.04LTS still didn't make any change. In fact, currently the stable PPA has a newer appcenter package than the daily! It seems elementary OS provides an upgraded packagekit from their patched packages PPA. However, adding this PPA to Ubuntu'd break stuff. So, I selectively upgraded packagekit using another PPA and met the dependency on _libpackagekit-glib2-18_ (with some less serious issues though)

Comment: @Terrance Can u do _apt policy libpackagekit-glib2-18_ on the 16.04LTS system you installed AppCenter and check which repo provides that package?

Comment: @HEXcube `http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: Would this work in 18.04?